# How do I transform nested components in separate jsx files with babel?

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I haven't used React in several months, and tonight I was trying to write jsx that is automatically compiled to jsx by babel according to [these directions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html).

I have two files like this:

Parent.jsx

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<Child></Child>);
  }
});
```

and

Child.jsx

```
var Child= React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<span>CHILD</span>);
  }
});
```

I am using babel to monitor the files for changes and output new js files when needed, and it always renders the Child component as `React.createElement("Child", null)` instead of `React.createElement(Child, null)` like I expect.

I'm new to babel and node in general and can't find a way to get this jsx transform to work as I expect.  Is there something I'm missing?  I feel like this pattern used to work, but I've never tried it with anything like babel before.

Comment: Looks right.  The first of all you have typo in Child component, not closed tag. this is your example. https://jsfiddle.net/nucdu5p1/

Comment: How do you import `Child` in Parent.jsx?

Comment: @DavinTryon - That's a good question.  I am not doing anything like that.  I couldn't find any examples of how to do it, and none of the options I tried worked.  I'm hoping that it's something really simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: In order to use `require` or `import` you will need some sort of bundler that respects modules.  webpack or browserfiy seem like the most popular choices at the moment.  Babel will hook into either.

Answer (score 0):

It took me what felt like forever to figure this out, but it turns out you can just load all the files from the HTML and then nest them later on.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

<script src="./Test3a.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="./Test3b.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<Ostrich />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<Monkey />, document.getElementById("test"));
</script>
```

Test3A.jsx:

```
window.Ostrich = function() {
    return (
        <div>
            Ostriches
        </div>
    );
}
```

window.Monkey = function() {
return (



);
}

Test3A.jsx:

```
window.MoreMonkeys = function() {
    return (
        <div>
            That's a lot of Monkeys.
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is for non-webpack "React JS", or more accurately Babel/JSX "without" ReactJS.  It may not be a perfect solution, but hopefully it helps.